# How to query mongo collection based on nested array size

Tags: mongodb

I want to write a query to find all documents based on nested array size.

```js
//collection data example

{
  prop1: 'value',
  prop2:{
          subprop1: [{Id:1,value:'abc'},{Id:2,value:'aa'}]
          subprop2: false
          }
},
{
  prop1: 'value2',
  prop2:{
          subprop1: [{Id:11,value:'ww'},{Id:21,value:'33'},{Id:31,value:'asd'}]
          subprop2: false
          }
},
{
  prop1: 'value3',
  prop2:null
},
{
  prop1: 'value4',
  prop2:{
          subprop1: null
          subprop2: false
          }
}
```

I tried following query but it is throwing error "this.prop2" is null.

```js
db.collection.find({prop2 : {$exists:true}, $where:'this.prop2.subprop1.length>1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

aggregate

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      prop2: {
        $exists: true
      },
      "prop2.subprop1": {
        $not: {
          "$eq": null
        }
      },
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: "$prop2.subprop1"
          },
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RBzuMA-kVXl)